# how to solve this error OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application?

Tags: numpy

**when I try to import numpy, it gives me oserror. I have 64 bit processor.error as follow**

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import numpy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
        from . import _distributor_init
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
        WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
      File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda31\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need python.exe to be visible on the search path, or you could pass the full path to the executable file that is running the calling script
--also make sure the softwares you're running is for 64-bit processor